# Python, How to zip and restructure complex data set

Tags: python, json

I am a new python user, and I have just been getting familiar with restructuring data with the zip function, however I am now faced with a challenging data set that i have to restructure. I have 3 json responses that I have to merge from my end, the data sets are identical in design and would have the same length, they just differ from environments they ran on.

**Let 3 files be the same values for brevity: qa.json | dev.json | prod.json**

*Note: This outer object is array/list of object, I just put one object for brevity*

```
[
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "keyword": "Scenario", 
      "name": "valid user can login site", 
      "steps": [
        {
          "name": "a valid user name and password", 
          "result": {
            "status": "passed"
          }
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "a valid user clicking on the login button after typing in user name and password", 
          "result": { 
            "status": "passed"
          }
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "map should display", 
          "result": {
            "status": "passed"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "keyword": "Feature", 
  "name": "login", 
  "status": "passed"
}
]
```

**What I want to achieve:**

*Note: i want to merge them in one set with different environments reflecting the status*

```
[
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "keyword": "Scenario", 
      "name": "valid user can login site", 
      "steps": [
        {
          "name": "a valid user name and password", 
          "result": {
            "qa": "passed",
            "prod": "passed",
            "dev": "passed"
          }
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "a valid user clicking on the login button after typing in user name and password", 
          "result": { 
            "qa": "passed",
            "prod": "passed",
            "dev": "passed"
          }
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "map should display", 
          "result": {
            "qa": "passed",
            "prod": "passed",
            "dev": "passed"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "keyword": "Feature", 
  "name": "login", 
  "qa": "passed",
  "prod": "passed",
  "dev": "passed"
}
]
```

**What i have done so far:**

*I come from a javascript background so i im still getting familiar with python logic*

```
import json

with open('qa.json') as data_file:    
    qa = json.load(data_file)

with open('dev.json') as data_file:    
    dev = json.load(data_file)

with open('prod.json') as data_file:    
    prod = json.load(data_file)

json_list = [{SOME STRUCT} for q, d, p in zip(qa, dev, prod)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a lot of time so I'm posting what I believe is a working solution to your problem even if it's slightly messy. If I have time I'll edit it.

**Code**

```
import json

data = """
[
{
    "elements": [{
        "keyword": "Scenario",
        "name": "valid user can login site",
        "steps": [{
            "name": "a valid user name and password",
            "result": {
                "status": "passed"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "a valid user clicking on the login button after typing in user name and password",
            "result": {
                "status": "passed"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "map should display",
            "result": {
                "status": "passed"
            }
        }]
    }],
    "keyword": "Feature",
    "name": "login",
    "status": "passed"
},
{
    "elements": [{
        "keyword": "Scenario",
        "name": "valid user can login site",
        "steps": [{
            "name": "a valid user name and password",
            "result": {
                "status": "passed"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "a valid user clicking on the login button after typing in user name and password",
            "result": {
                "status": "failed"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "map should display",
            "result": {
                "status": "passed"
            }
        }]
    }],
    "keyword": "Feature",
    "name": "login",
    "status": "passed"
}
]
"""

def get_result(envData, objIndex, elementIndex, stepIndex):
    return envData[objIndex]['elements'][elementIndex]['steps'][stepIndex]['result']['status']

def set_combined_results(combinedData, objIndex, elementIndex, stepIndex, results):
    resultNode = combinedData[objIndex]['elements'][elementIndex]['steps'][stepIndex]['result']
    resultNode.update({ 'qa': results[0], 'prod': results[1], 'dev': results[2] })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qAData = json.loads(data)
    prodData = json.loads(data)
    devData = json.loads(data)
    combinedData = json.loads(data)

    for objIndex, obj in enumerate(combinedData):
        for elementIndex, element in enumerate(obj['elements']):
            for stepIndex, _ in enumerate(element['steps']):
                qAResult = get_result(qAData, objIndex, elementIndex, stepIndex)
                prodResult = get_result(prodData, objIndex, elementIndex, stepIndex)
                devResult = get_result(devData, objIndex, elementIndex, stepIndex)
                combinedResults = (qAResult, prodResult, devResult)
                set_combined_results(combinedData, objIndex, elementIndex, stepIndex, combinedResults)

        qAAggregateResult = qAData[objIndex]['status']
        prodAggregateResult = prodData[objIndex]['status']
        devAggregateResult = devData[objIndex]['status']

        del combinedData[objIndex]['status']
        combinedData[objIndex]['qa'] = qAAggregateResult
        combinedData[objIndex]['prod'] = prodAggregateResult
        combinedData[objIndex]['dev'] = devAggregateResult

    print(json.dumps(combinedData, indent=True))
```

**Output**

```
[
 {
  "keyword": "Feature",
  "name": "login",
  "elements": [
   {
    "keyword": "Scenario",
    "name": "valid user can login site",
    "steps": [
     {
      "result": {
       "qa": "passed",
       "status": "passed",
       "dev": "passed",
       "prod": "passed"
      },
      "name": "a valid user name and password"
     },
     {
      "result": {
       "qa": "passed",
       "status": "passed",
       "dev": "passed",
       "prod": "passed"
      },
      "name": "a valid user clicking on the login button after typing in user name and password"
     },
     {
      "result": {
       "qa": "passed",
       "status": "passed",
       "dev": "passed",
       "prod": "passed"
      },
      "name": "map should display"
     }
    ]
   }
  ],
  "dev": "passed",
  "prod": "passed",
  "qa": "passed"
 },
 {
  "keyword": "Feature",
  "name": "login",
  "elements": [
   {
    "keyword": "Scenario",
    "name": "valid user can login site",
    "steps": [
     {
      "result": {
       "qa": "passed",
       "status": "passed",
       "dev": "passed",
       "prod": "passed"
      },
      "name": "a valid user name and password"
     },
     {
      "result": {
       "qa": "failed",
       "status": "failed",
       "dev": "failed",
       "prod": "failed"
      },
      "name": "a valid user clicking on the login button after typing in user name and password"
     },
     {
      "result": {
       "qa": "passed",
       "status": "passed",
       "dev": "passed",
       "prod": "passed"
      },
      "name": "map should display"
     }
    ]
   }
  ],
  "dev": "failed",
  "prod": "failed",
  "qa": "failed"
 }
]
```

Comment: nice, but you forgot the outermost object has to reflect the status for different environments as well. Thank you, please edit if you can to reflect outer most object

Comment: Oh, missed that part of your post.

Comment: I deleted the last comment i was wrong.. Thank you please update to reflect outer most status

Comment: It supports multiple objects (demonstrated in edited post). I've updated to include the outermost status.

Answer (score 0):

Because each object in the `list` is a `dict` you can use `dict.update` mehthod to update a `dict`.
f.e.

```
a = [{'one': 1}, {'three': 3}]
b = [{'one': 1}, {'two': 2}] # {'one': 1} is duplicate with same value
c = [{'a': 'aaa'}, {'two': 22}] # {'two': 22} is duplicate with different value

for x, y, z in zip(a, b, c):
    x.update(y)
    x.update(z)
```

Now `x` would be `[{'a': 'aaa', 'one': 1}, {'three': 3, 'two': 22}]`

For those json files you mentioned, it would be;

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

qa = '''
[
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "keyword": "Scenario", 
      "name": "valid user can login site", 
      "steps": [
        {
          "name": "a valid user name and password", 
          "result": {
            "qa": "passed"
          }
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "a valid user clicking on the login button after typing in user name and password", 
          "result": { 
            "qa": "passed"
          }
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "map should display", 
          "result": {
            "qa": "passed"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "keyword": "Feature", 
  "name": "login", 
  "qa": "passed"
}
]
'''
dev = '''
[
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "keyword": "Scenario", 
      "name": "valid user can login site", 
      "steps": [
        {
          "name": "a valid user name and password", 
          "result": {
            "dev": "passed"
          }
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "a valid user clicking on the login button after typing in user name and password", 
          "result": { 
            "dev": "passed"
          }
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "map should display", 
          "result": {
            "dev": "passed"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "keyword": "Feature", 
  "name": "login", 
  "dev": "passed"
}
]
'''
prod = '''
[
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "keyword": "Scenario", 
      "name": "valid user can login site", 
      "steps": [
        {
          "name": "a valid user name and password", 
          "result": {
            "prod": "passed"
          }
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "a valid user clicking on the login button after typing in user name and password", 
          "result": { 
            "prod": "passed"
          }
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "map should display", 
          "result": {
            "prod": "passed"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "keyword": "Feature", 
  "name": "login", 
  "prod": "passed"
}
]
'''
qa = json.loads(qa)
dev = json.loads(dev)
prod = json.loads(prod)

for q, p, d in zip(qa, dev, prod):
    # update all keys but 'elements'
    q.update({k: v for k, v in p.items() if k != 'elements'})
    q.update({k: v for k, v in d.items() if k != 'elements'})

    # update the three 'result' dict
    for i in range(3):
        q['elements'][0]['steps'][i]['result'].update(p['elements'][0]['steps'][i]['result'])
        q['elements'][0]['steps'][i]['result'].update(d['elements'][0]['steps'][i]['result'])

pprint(qa)
```

Output;

```
[{'dev': 'passed',
  'elements': [{'keyword': 'Scenario',
                'name': 'valid user can login site',
                'steps': [{'name': 'a valid user name and password',
                           'result': {'dev': 'passed',
                                      'prod': 'passed',
                                      'qa': 'passed'}},
                          {'name': 'a valid user clicking on the login button '
                                   'after typing in user name and password',   
                           'result': {'dev': 'passed',
                                      'prod': 'passed',
                                      'qa': 'passed'}},
                          {'name': 'map should display',
                           'result': {'dev': 'passed',  
                                      'prod': 'passed',
                                      'qa': 'passed'}}]}],
  'keyword': 'Feature',
  'name': 'login',
  'prod': 'passed',
  'qa': 'passed'}]
```

Comment: This assumes that the "merge" the OP wants is the `update` form of merge, I.E. x will wind up with the keys in precedence order of `z, y, z`. It's very unclear from their question if this is the behavior they actually desire, or if they're trying to keep the results separate but merge them all into some kind of super-dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive merge implementation. It will merge arbitrary types of Python objects, such that anything but `dicts` must be equal when merged.

For `dicts`, it will allow merging if the same keys are associated with mergable values in those where the key is present. Any `dict` keys equalling the  parameter `fieldname` will be suffixed with an index before merging:

```
from copy import deepcopy
from itertools import chain

def merge(field_name, *objs):
    # Make sure all objs are of same type
    types = list(set(map(type, objs)))
    if not len(set(map(type, objs))) == 1:
        raise Exception('Cannot merge objects of different types: {types}'.format(types=types))

    first = objs[0]
    # for any random objects, make sure they are equal!
    if not isinstance(first, (list, tuple, dict)):
        if not len(set(objs)) == 1:  
            raise Exception("Cannot merge non-equal objects that aren't dicts: {objs}".format(objs=objs))
        return deepcopy(first)

    # for lists, tuples: zip 'em and merge the zipped elements
    if isinstance(first, (list, tuple)):
        return [merge(field_name, *zipped) for zipped in zip(*objs)]

    # dicts
    result_dict = {}
    keys = list(set(chain.from_iterable(d.keys() for d in objs)))
    try:
        keys.remove(field_name)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    for k in keys:
        # merge values from all dicts where key is present
        result_dict[k] = merge(field_name, *(d[k] for d in objs if k in d))
    for i, d in enumerate(objs):
        if field_name in d:
            result_dict['{f}_{i}'.format(f=field_name, i=i)] = d[field_name]
    return result_dict
```

This can now be used on `dev, qa, prod` that are `dicts` of the structure given by th OP:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(merge('status', qa, dev, prod))
[{'elements': [{'keyword': 'Scenario',
                'name': 'valid user can login site',
                'steps': [{'name': 'a valid user name and password',
                           'result': {'status_0': 'passed',
                                      'status_1': 'passed',
                                      'status_2': 'passed'}},
                          {'name': 'a valid user clicking on the login button after typing in user name and password',
                           'result': {'status_0': 'passed',
                                      'status_1': 'passed',
                                      'status_2': 'passed'}},
                          {'name': 'map should display',
                           'result': {'status_0': 'passed',
                                      'status_1': 'passed',
                                      'status_2': 'passed'}}]}],
  'keyword': 'Feature',
  'name': 'login',
  'status_0': 'passed',
  'status_1': 'passed',
  'status_2': 'passed'}]
```

This is, of course, not fully generic, e.g. it only "deep" merges sequences when they are `lists` or `tuples`, but it should be decent enough for data structures loaded from json. I hope it helps you find a solution.